# Not receiving headers Scrapy ProxyMesh

Tags: python, proxy, header, scrapy

I am quite new to Scrapy / ProxyMesh.
My request to the Proxymesh server seems to be working as I see my bandwith consumption on the ProxyMesh website, and the meta.proxy is correct in my logs.
However, when I log the response headers in Scrapy, I do not receive the X-Proxymesh-IP that I am supposed to receive.
Here is my code. What am I doing wrong?

This is my middleware

```
class Proxymesh(object):

 def __init__(self):

    logging.debug('Initialized Proxymesh middleware')

    self.proxy_ip = 'http://host:port'

 def process_request(self, request, spider):

    logging.debug('Processing request through proxy IP: ' + self.proxy_ip)

    request.meta['proxy'] = self.proxy_ip
```

These are my settings in my spider

```
custom_settings = {
    "DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES": {
        "projectName.middlewares.proxymesh.Proxymesh" : 1,
     }
```

This is what the response headers look like

```
['Set-Cookie']:['__cfduid=d88d4e4cb7... HttpOnly']
['Vary']:['User-Agent,Accept-Encoding']
['Server']:['cloudflare-nginx']
['Date']:['Thu, 19 Oct 2017 10...38:10 GMT']
['Cf-Ray']:['3b031b30cbef1565-CDG']
['Content-Type']:['text/html; charset=UTF-8']
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this relevant anymore but I'm going to post it here. There's an issue with proxymesh and scrapy or python requests.
When connecting to a proxy, a CONNECT request is sent to the proxy service in order to create a tunnel which will forward the actual request.
If the request is successful, proxymesh adds the X-Proxymesh-IP in the CONNECT requests's confirmation response. This is header totally missed by scrapy as it only takes into consideration the response headers of the actual request.

This only happens to HTTPS requests because the content of the actual request is encrypted.

References:

https://docs.proxymesh.com/article/74-proxy-server-headers-over-https

https://bugs.python.org/issue24964?fbclid=IwAR1c88hpLu2OdmEXlwfZfb2n8lMIqT8JvjLeO7pzsvFEiZBVlfJNpYZ4aFk

https://github.com/requests/requests/issues/3061?fbclid=IwAR34XDJa7dJqNpH33LRlvpoRHpaZJhVl75zXfFkEuBa7IjOVCoIxecW0zhw

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to do this too?

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
     'scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware': 1,
}
```

And also in your callback function, are you sure you are printing `response.headers`

Comment: Hey @Umair adding the httpproxy middleware does not change anything. Also, the response headers are printed in the callback of my spider. Would there be another way to access these X-Proxymesh-IP headers?

Comment: I have used proxymesh few months ago... it should be working alright... can you please share your full code?

Comment: Also please make sure your proxy is working or not. Scrape any website IP to check which IP is returned back